# Getting VBOs to work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I have problems getting OpenGL to work, basically I am getting alternate black and grey screens. I have it working fine using the fixed function pipeline (glBegin(), glEnd() and glTexCoord...) I think I am doing something very wrong, pretty new to this stuff. Any help would be appreciated.

```
struct Quad
{
    float x0, y0, z0;   // top left corner
    float x1, y1, z1;   // top right corner
    float x2, y2, z2;   // bottom left corner
    float x3, y3, z3;   // bottom right corner
    float s0, t0;
    float s1, t1;
    float s2, t2;
    float s3, t3;
    char r, g, b, a;    // tint
    float depth;        // depth value of the Quad
};

void draw{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    // Note: glVertexPointer is deprecated, change to glVertexAttribPointer
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Quad), &(vertexBuffer_[0].x0));
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Quad), &(vertexBuffer_[0].s0));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs_[activeVBO_]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_.size() * sizeof(Quad), &(vertexBuffer_[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertexBuffer_.size());
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    activeVBO_ = (++activeVBO_)%NUM_VBO;
    glError();
}
```

Comment: Managed to fix some of the issues - In addition to what genpfault pointed out, I was also missing a call to clear(), so the frame buffer was not being reset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use some odd combination of vertex arrays and VBOs.  Try [this walkthrough](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html).

Strange things:

- `gl*Pointer()` calls should use zero-based "pointers" instead of real pointers if you're using VBOs.
- Your `Quad` struct is kinda weird.  I'm not quite sure you can write 
  usable `stride` values for it.  Try an array of these:

> ```
> struct Vertex
> {
>     float x, y, z;
>     float s, t;
>     char r, g, b, a;
> };
> ```